# How did the electronic components in Parker Solar probe responsible for controlling it and communicating with base station survive high temperatures?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, semiconductor-physics, satellites, nasa

The recent revelations by Nasa that their solar probe had been closer to the Sun by never before distances and aims at getting close to Sun by a mere 6.9 times radius of the Sun around year 2025. Given that surface temperature of Sun is estimated to be(quite unequivocally) around 5500K and it is quite normal for probe's electronic components to reach temperatures of several hundred degrees (despite thermal insulation due to long exposures from/to ambient radiation and also by thermal conduction). Given that semiconductors show their "semi-conductive" nature best at low temperatures and continue to do so till few hundred degree Celsius above which they either melt or become regular conductors(M.P. of Si=1410 degree Celsius) and generally loose their electron flow controlling property for good. How did Physicists achieved the difficult feat of keeping semiconductors operational even when the whole probe stayed near the Sun for so long ?

Comment: Getting to equilibrium requires time, so they don't instantly heat up. Also, while the sun facing side is hot, the opposite side is looking at a very cold universe.

Comment: The heat shield keeps nearly all electronic systems in shadow and heat conduction from the plasma is effectively zero even close to the Sun.  The few systems in direct sunlight are made of special materials that can operate at very high temperatures.